# Query JPA ElementCollection with List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How do I query an `@ElementCollection` containing at least one element of my search criteria?

Given this corresponding database schema

[image: ER diagram]

for this entity class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name="companies_products",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    )
    @Column(name="product")
    private List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();

    // ... getters/setters
}
```

I want to query the database for companies with a list of products. In SQL I can do

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.*
    FROM companies c
    LEFT JOIN companies_products cp ON c.id = cp.company_id
    WHERE
        cp.product IN ('food', 'electronics', 'books')
```

How whould an equivalent HQL/JPQL query look like?

I found [Hibernate's collection-related expressions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-collection-expressions) and [qualified-path expressions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-collection-qualification) but I was unable to create a working query.

- `FROM Company c WHERE c.products IN (:prods)` using `List.of("food", "electronics", "books")` as named parameter

  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [phones] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [food] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
- `FROM Company c WHERE value(c.products) IN (:prods)`

  Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CompanyRepository.findWithProducts(java.util.List)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CompanyRepository.findWithProducts(java.util.List)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CompanyRepository.findWithProducts(java.util.List)!
- `FROM Company c WHERE elements(c.products) IN (:prods)`

  Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CompanyRepository.findWithProducts(java.util.List)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CompanyRepository.findWithProducts(java.util.List)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.CompanyRepository.findWithProducts(java.util.List)!

Comment: You might try "Select c FROM Company c join c.products p WHERE p IN (:prods)", but as the validation comes from spring, you might show the repository methods being used as well. The first error mentions phones which you haven't specified at all in your description, so I suspect your method signature is the problem there.

Comment: The phones were a copy/paste error. I fixed my post but your suggestion already solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Chris. Your suggested query `Select c FROM Company c join c.products p WHERE p IN (:prods)` works. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've had to do left join:

```
Select c FROM Company c left join c.products p WHERE p IN (:prods)
```

Join by default is an inner join, so you won't get any results with empty c.products.